# Definition of Series of Meromorphic Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Let $D\subset \Bbb{C}$ be non-empty, open, and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of meromorphic functions on $D$. In Henri Cartan's complex analysis book, the following definition is given:

> We say the series $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on a subset $A\subset D$ if there is an $n_0\in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $f_n$ has no poles in $A$, and the series $\sum_{n\geq n_0}f_n$ converges uniformly on $A$.

While I understand the definition, I was wondering if there is a way to phrase the definition "more naturally". What I mean is that usually, one starts by defining concepts for sequences of functions $\{f_n\}$, and then defines similar concepts for series by applying the sequential definition to the partial sums $s_n:= \sum_{i=1}^nf_i$. So, there's a nice "symmetry" in the definitions for sequences and series, but by the way the definition is phrased above, it seems this "symmetry" is broken because one first requires the existence of an $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that blablabla.

So, I'm asking if it is possible to first define the concept of "uniform convergence of a sequence of meromorphic functions on a subset $A\subset D$", and then somehow naturally defining the concept of "uniform convergence of a series of meromorphic functions on a subset $A\subset D$".

Comment: You could start off by saying that only finitely many $f_n$ have a pole in $A$.

Comment: Cartan is not trying to re-invent the wheel here. The concept of uniform convergence on a domain is already defined on series of complex functions. But meromorphic functions extend that concept of domain to include poles. So the only thing needed, or even desirable, here is to extend the existing definition to include poles. For reasons I won't get into, he chose to deal with poles by demanding that there only be finitely many in the limit. But as every pole in the $f_n$ is also a pole in the limit, this means that there cannot more than a finite number of $f_n$ with poles.